# How to access a function in the scope by an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, event-handling

Here a simple example:

```js
  $(function(){ ///scope
            function alerter(number){
                switch(number){
                    case 1:
                        alert("first");
                    break;
                    
                    case 2:
                        alert("second");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

```css
 #first{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: red;
        }
        
        #second{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: blue;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" onclick="alerter(1)">
    </div>
    <div id="second" onclick="alerter(2)">
    </div>
```

The error message says: "alerter is not defined"

I cant use the js .click() function (or an eventlistener) in my project, bacause there are not permanent piece of divs.

Of course it would work if the "alerter" function wasn't be inside the scope function, but i don't want to declare global variables.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you don't want globals how are you going to use it in the HTML file...? Bind listeners in the JS files or else globals are needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you won't declare it as a global function the html won't be able to call it. If you wan't you can reverse your logic and do something like the following.

```js
$(function() { ///scope
  $("#first").on("click", function() {
    alerter(1);
  });

  $("#second").on("click", function() {
    alerter(2);
  });

  function alerter(number) {
    switch (number) {
      case 1:
        alert("first");
        break;

      case 2:
        alert("second");
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#first {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#second {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
</div>
```

This way you can keep your global scope clean and yet you'll have the same functionality.

Comment: As i said a cant use eventlisteners in my project.

Comment: Then there is no way to keep you global scope clean.

Comment: @HowardFring Then you're screwed. Javascript in HTML attributes can only access the global scope. So you either need global variables or adding the listeners with JS.

Comment: @HowardFring Can you use `document.getElementById('first').onclick = ...`?

Comment: yeah, it seems the only way

Comment: @Barmar i can't

Comment: @HowardFring You can minimize the number of global variables by putting them all in an object. Then you just need to use `objectName.alerter(1)`

Comment: yeah, I know this will happen

Comment: @Barmar That's the only other way I can think of as to keep the global as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that "alerter" is defined into the temporary scope created by the call to the anonymous function.

If you want it outside of its scope you need to do something like

```
window.alerter = function alerter...
```

[Edit]

Since you don't want to declare a "global" variable, you'll need to stick the event using js, cf comment.

And you can do it using delegated events aka jQuery's "on" method. It does not need permanent divs for it to work.

Comment: *"Of course it would work if the "alerter" function wasn't be inside the scope function, but i don't want to declare global variables."*

Comment: Then you need to place the event using javascript inside the anonymous function, since its the only place where you can have a reference to alerter. Using something like jQuery' on or native addEventListener.

Comment: Tell that to the OP.

Comment: @Barmar I know that... hence my comment on the original question. I'm notifying the answerer of it. Maybe mention 'the only way to use the function in HTML is to use globals'.

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you explained what you are trying to achieve with this code. Is there a specific reason for using switch statements? You may want to consider using jQuery .on event as @dader pointed out. An example being:

$("#first").on('click', function() { alert("First") })

Comment: I can't bacause as many HTML elements will be rendered by javascript as many are in the database.